# Concerning crossproduct and orthonormality of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

If you have 3 orthonormal vectors, $\pmatrix{u_1 \\ u_2 \\ u_3}$, $\pmatrix{v_1 \\ v_2 \\ v_3}$, $\pmatrix{w_1 \\ w_2 \\ w_3}$ such that $u= v \times w$ (crossproduct) can it be true that $v_i v_j + w_i w_j= - u_i u_j$?

I also get that $w_i ^2 + v_i ^3 = 1- u_i ^2$. How do you explain this? 
I am working with some product of vectors and I get that this must be true?

Answer (score 0):

Combining them into a matrix
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
u_1 & v_1 & w_1\\
u_2 & v_2 & w_2\\
u_3 & v_3 & w_3
\end{bmatrix}$$
then what you've observed can be restated as:

$$(\textsf{row }i)\cdot(\textsf{row }j)=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if }i=j,\\
0 & \text{if }i\neq j
\end{cases}$$
In other words, you've observed that if we make a square matrix $A$ with orthonormal columns, then the rows of $A$ are also orthonormal to each other.

The rows of $A$ are just the columns of the transpose matrix, denoted $A^{\mathsf{T}}$.

A square matrix whose columns are orthonormal to each other is called an "orthogonal matrix" (poor naming choice, unfortunately). [See here on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix).

Thus, the final restatement of what you've observed is that the transpose of an orthogonal matrix is again an orthogonal matrix.

---

How to prove this observation?

Note that because the columns of $A$ are orthonormal, we have
$$A^{\mathsf{T}}A=\begin{pmatrix}
u\cdot u & u\cdot v & u\cdot w\\
v\cdot u & v\cdot v & v\cdot w\\
w\cdot u & w\cdot v & w\cdot w
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}=I$$
It is an important fact that for any square matrices $A$ and $B$, if we have $BA=I$, then we must also have $AB=I$. [There is a stack exchange thread about that here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3852/184154).

But now, observe that because $A^{\mathsf{T}}A=I$, we must have $AA^{\mathsf{T}}=I$, so that
$$AA^{\mathsf{T}}=\begin{pmatrix}
(\textsf{row }1)\cdot(\textsf{row }1) & (\textsf{row }1)\cdot(\textsf{row }2) & (\textsf{row }1)\cdot(\textsf{row }3)\\
(\textsf{row }2)\cdot(\textsf{row }1) & (\textsf{row }2)\cdot(\textsf{row }2) & (\textsf{row }2)\cdot(\textsf{row }3)\\
(\textsf{row }3)\cdot(\textsf{row }1) & (\textsf{row }3)\cdot(\textsf{row }2) & (\textsf{row }3)\cdot(\textsf{row }3)
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}=I$$
Thus the rows of $A$ are also orthonormal to each other.

Comment: Thank you so much, that made things very clear :)

Comment: Happy to help! [If my answer is satisfactory you can accept it by clicking the checkmark](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)